# How to draw an object and rotate it in oblique frontal projection

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, pascal, projection-matrix

How to draw an object and rotate it in **oblique frontal** (*dimetric*) projection properly?

An illustration of projection:

[image: Oblique frontal projection]

I've already made a program (*Pascal with Graph unit*) which does it, but I think that it draws object incorrectly.

```
program p7test;

uses PtcCrt, PtcGraph;

type
  TPixel = record
    x, y, z: real;
  end;
  TModel = record
    p: array [ 1..8 ] of TPixel;
  end;
  TCenter = record
    xc, zc: integer;
  end;

var
  Driver, Mode: integer;
  c: char;
  s: string;
  ns, rx, ry, rz, ra, m_l, m_w, m_h, m_l_d, m_w_d, m_h_d: integer;
  model_d, model: TModel;
  center: TCenter;

  procedure LineXYZ( sp_t, ep_t: TPixel; center_t: TCenter );
  var
    x1, y1, x2, y2: real;
  begin
    x1 := sp_t.x - sin( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
    y1 := sp_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
    x2 := ep_t.x - sin( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
    y2 := ep_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
    Line(
      round( center_t.xc - x1 ),
      round( center_t.zc - y1 ),
      round( center_t.xc - x2 ),
      round( center_t.zc - y2 )
    );
  end;

  procedure DrawModel( model_t: TModel; center_t: TCenter );
  var
    i: integer;
  begin
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 1 ], model_t.p[ 2 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 2 ], model_t.p[ 3 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 3 ], model_t.p[ 4 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 4 ], model_t.p[ 1 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 5 ], model_t.p[ 6 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 6 ], model_t.p[ 7 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 7 ], model_t.p[ 8 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 8 ], model_t.p[ 5 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 1 ], model_t.p[ 5 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 2 ], model_t.p[ 6 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 3 ], model_t.p[ 7 ], center_t );
    LineXYZ( model_t.p[ 4 ], model_t.p[ 8 ], center_t );
  end;

  function RotateZ( model_t: TModel; angle: real ): TModel;
  var
    x, y: real;
    i: integer;
  begin
    angle := angle * pi / 180;
    for i := 1 to 8 do
    begin
      x := model_t.p[ i ].x;
      y := model_t.p[ i ].y;
      model_t.p[ i ].x := x * cos( angle ) - y * sin( angle );
      model_t.p[ i ].y := y * cos( angle ) + x * sin( angle );
    end;
    RotateZ := model_t;
  end;

  function RotateY( model_t: TModel; angle: real ): TModel;
  var
    x, z: real;
    i: integer;
  begin
    angle := angle * pi / 180;
    for i := 1 to 8 do
    begin
      x := model_t.p[ i ].x;
      z := model_t.p[ i ].z;
      model_t.p[ i ].x := x * cos( angle ) - z * sin( angle );
      model_t.p[ i ].z := z * cos( angle ) + x * sin( angle );
    end;
    RotateY := model_t;
  end;

  function RotateX( model_t: TModel; angle: real ): TModel;
  var
    y, z: real;
    i: integer;
  begin
    angle := angle * pi / 180;
    for i := 1 to 8 do
    begin
      y := model_t.p[ i ].y;
      z := model_t.p[ i ].z;
      model_t.p[ i ].y := y * cos( angle ) - z * sin( angle );
      model_t.p[ i ].z := z * cos( angle ) + y * sin( angle );
    end;
    RotateX := model_t;
  end;

  function RotateXYZ( model_t: TModel; rx_t, ry_t, rz_t: integer ): TModel;
  begin
    model_t := RotateX( model_t, rx_t );
    model_t := RotateY( model_t, ry_t );
    model_t := RotateZ( model_t, rz_t );
    RotateXYZ := model_t;
  end;

begin
  Driver := D8bit;
  Mode := m800x600;
  InitGraph( Driver, Mode, '' );
  ra := 2;
  if ( GraphResult <> GrOk ) then WriteLn( '640x480x256''s not supported' ) else
  begin
    ClearDevice;
    center.xc := ( GetMaxX div 2 ) + 1;
    center.zc := ( GetMaxY div 2 ) + 1;
    m_l_d := 200; m_w_d := 200; m_h_d := 200;
    m_l := m_l_d; m_w := m_w_d; m_h := m_h_d;
    rx := -26; ry := 6; rz := 16;

    model_d.p[ 1 ].x := - m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 1 ].y := - m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 1 ].z := - m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 2 ].x := - m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 2 ].y :=   m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 2 ].z := - m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 3 ].x :=   m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 3 ].y :=   m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 3 ].z := - m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 4 ].x :=   m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 4 ].y := - m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 4 ].z := - m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 5 ].x := - m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 5 ].y := - m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 5 ].z :=   m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 6 ].x := - m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 6 ].y :=   m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 6 ].z :=   m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 7 ].x :=   m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 7 ].y :=   m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 7 ].z :=   m_h / 2;
    model_d.p[ 8 ].x :=   m_l / 2; model_d.p[ 8 ].y := - m_w / 2; model_d.p[ 8 ].z :=   m_h / 2;

    model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz );
    SetColor( 2 ); DrawModel( model, center );
    SetColor( 12 );
    Str( rx, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 2, 'rx=' + s );
    Str( ry, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 12, 'ry=' + s );
    Str( rz, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 22, 'rz=' + s );

    repeat Delay( 100 ) until KeyPressed;
    if ns = 0 then ns := 1 else ns := 0;
    ReadKey;
    repeat
      c := ReadKey;
      case c of
        #113: begin rx := rx - ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #101: begin rx := rx + ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #119: begin ry := ry - ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #115: begin ry := ry + ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #97: begin rz := rz - ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #100: begin rz := rz + ra; model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz ); end;
        #117: begin
          rx := 0; ry := 0; rz := 0;
          model := RotateXYZ( model_d, rx, ry, rz );
        end;
      end;
      ClearDevice;

      SetColor( 2 ); DrawModel( model, center );
      SetColor( 12 );
      Str( rx, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 2, 'rx=' + s );
      Str( ry, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 12, 'ry=' + s );
      Str( rz, s ); OutTextXY( 2, 22, 'rz=' + s );

      if ns = 0 then
      begin
        SetActivePage(0);
        SetVisualPage(1)
      end
      else
      begin
        SetActivePage(1);
        SetVisualPage(0)
      end;
      if ns = 0 then ns := 1 else ns := 0;
    until c = #27;
    CloseGraph;
  end;
end.
```

You might use <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys to rotate an object.

So, as you might notice in animation below, there's some issue when you're looking at it and it's slightly elongated:

[image: Object rotation 1]

Shouldn't it look like one below?:

[image: Object rotation 2]

I tried to change `LineXYZ()` code lines to this:

```
x1 := sp_t.x - ( sp_t.y / 2 );
y1 := sp_t.z - ( sp_t.y / 2 );
x2 := ep_t.x - ( ep_t.y / 2 );
y2 := ep_t.z - ( ep_t.y / 2 );
```

, but it might be incorrect, too.

---

Am I rotating **x**, **y**, **z** coordinates with functions like (Rotate*) correctly?
By the way, I think that the main problem is a **LineXYZ()** function(**y** coordinate part).
How to draw an object in this type of projection?

Thank you very much, as needed.

Best regards,
V7

Comment: The slight elongation is, of course, strictly a visual illusion. You need to use ["perspective" drawing](https://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm) techniques and choose imaginary focal points and compute your coordinates with that modification.

Comment: Dear @lurker as you see here https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohs85jCAleB5LwHUQ/giphy.gif there's no illusion. Isn't it ? So why then it is in my code ? is it because of **y / 2** ? So .. I think this's not an illusion. Just try to rate it only *right* and you'll see what happens.

Comment: I say it's an illusion because the back edge, which appears longer, is actually identical in length (on the screen) as the edge in the foreground. I snapshot your image and measured it. But the back edge appears longer due to perspective. The eyes/brain are interpreting the object as a 3D cube, but the lengths don't look right to support that notion. You need to *create the illusion* of proper depth and proportion by using  perspective techniques as described in the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you very much @lurker, but is it necessary for perspectiveness in this type of projection ? I mean ... isn't this projection orthographic ?

Comment: If you want it not to appear that the background edge is longer than the foreground edge, you must apply some kind of perspective element. In an orthographic projection, the projection lines are orthogonal to the projection surface (or the plane of view in this case). It doesn't provide the illusion of correct dimension when perceived in 3D that you are looking for.

Comment: `Isn't it should look like one below?` - Not, below is 90-90 projection, while your is 135-90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it should look like one below?

Not, gif below is 90-90 projection, while your axis are 135-90

Your code is correct, except two things:

1. Your X axis is wrong directed
2. You use `sin` instead of `cos`, while angle is `pi/4` they're same, but if you plan to change angle...

Your code:

```
x1 := sp_t.x - sin( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
y1 := sp_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
x2 := ep_t.x - sin( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
y2 := ep_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
```

Should be:

```
x1 := -sp_t.x - cos( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
y1 :=  sp_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * sp_t.y / 2;
x2 := -ep_t.x - cos( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
y2 :=  ep_t.z - sin( pi / 4 ) * ep_t.y / 2;
```

In rest your render is correct.

[Live Demo](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-3d-tutorial-4-frontdimetrical-projection/6110352034693120)

---

*About @lurker notes:

No reason to fix perspective illusion here (it's something personificated - impossible to compensate it for all viewers equally).*

This gif just demonstrate this illusion effect:
[image: Illusion Demonstration]

Comment: Thank you very much @vp_arth ... you've really helped me out.

Comment: *No reason to fix perspective illusion here (it's something personificated - impossible to compensate it for all viewers equally).* This is true. But in this case, there is only one viewer/perspective, so it can be compensated.